# Smarty layout tpl with Codeigniter with subView

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, smarty3

I have integrated smarty with codeigniter and I know basic of them but I am having a issue of handling the layout, even though i have create but still I am confuse how to make it work more efficiently,

I have a layout in which header, footer, menu and body layout, in body it will be depend on the which page is showing, now my page middle contain have 4-5 tpl included and then those 2-3 tlp also have sub tpl file so what will be the way to feed the data to those sub tpl, I dont want then to feed by only one laoding controller because that will be messy, Is there any way that those tpl section can have there own controller and somehow pass the data which needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are on the wrong track!

You should use the `{extends}` syntax to take advantage of [template inheritance](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.template.inheritance.tpl).

Start with your base template file (we'll call it template.php). This file will include your header and footer code, and more if you want.

**template.tpl:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{$title|default:'Default Page Title'}</title>
    {block name=head}{/block}
</head>
<body>
    {block name=content}{/block}
</body>
</html>
```

Then, your individual pages would {extend} the main template file, and specify the necessary content for all of the blocks. Note that you can make blocks optional and with default values, so there is no requirement to fill all blocks (unless you code it that way).

**content_page.tpl:**

```
{extends file="template.tpl"}

{block name=head}
<link href="/assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/assets/js/mypage.js"></script>
{/block}

{block name=content}
<h1>Content Page</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
{/block}
```

And in the controller: `$this->custom_smarty->display('content_page.tpl');`